# Joining Tables on Time, IF NULL edit time by 1 minute

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I have two tables.

```
Table 1 = My Trades
Table 2 = Market Trades
```

I want query the market trade 1 minute prior to my trade.  If there is no market trade in Table 2 that is 1 minute apart from mine then I want to look back 2 minutes and so on till I have a match.

Right now my query gets me 1 minute apart but I cant figure out how to get 2 minutes apart if NULL or 3 minutes apart if NULL (up to 30 minutes).  I think it would best using a variable but im not sure the best way to approach this.

```
Select 
 A.Ticker 
,a.date_time
,CONVERT(CHAR(16),a.date_time - '00:01',120) AS '1MINCHANGE'
,A.Price
,B.Date_time
,B.Price
FROM
Trade..MyTrade as A
LEFT JOIN Trade..Market as B 
on (a.ticker = b.ticker) 
and (CONVERT(CHAR(16),a.date_time - '00:01',120) = b.Date_time)
```

Comment: Sorry about that Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no great way to do this in MySQL.  But, because your code looks like SQL Server, I'll show that solution here, using `APPLY`:

```
select t.Ticker ,
       convert(CHAR(16), t.date_time - '00:01', 120) AS '1MINCHANGE',
       t.Price,
       m.Date_time,
       m.Price
from Trade..MyTrade as t outer apply
     (select top 1 m.*
      from Trade..Market m
      where a.ticker = b.ticker and
            convert(CHAR(16), t.date_time - '00:01', 120) >= b.Date_time)
      order by m.DateTime desc
     ) m;
```

Comment: It worked thank you! the market is a large table so it took some time but it worked.